# Why are polynomials of even powers better for Pollard's rho?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-factorization

Taking all $C(900,2)$ combinations of the first 900 prime numbers, I defined $N = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are a combination of primes.  Then I factored $N$ using Pollard's Rho, counting how many iterations and how many successes were found, where a success is finding a non-trivial factor and an iteration is a computation of the GCD algorithm.

Notice how even powers have much better performance while keeping about the same number of successes.  Can you explain that?

```
iterations  sucesses  polynomial
 784491     44081     x^2 + 1, x0 = 2
 831938     44098     x^2 + 1, x0 = 3
3380606     44505     x^3 + 1, x0 = 2
3176223     44511     x^3 + 1, x0 = 3
 566286     43757     x^4 + 1, x0 = 2
 581990     43765     x^4 + 1, x0 = 3
5912991     44646     x^5 + 1, x0 = 2
6050589     44622     x^5 + 1, x0 = 3
 486181     43630     x^6 + 1, x0 = 2
 507281     43707     x^6 + 1, x0 = 3
7514619     44717     x^7 + 1, x0 = 2
7884300     44727     x^7 + 1, x0 = 3
 528307     43822     x^8 + 1, x0 = 2
 528177     43809     x^8 + 1, x0 = 3
3139981     44455     x^9 + 1, x0 = 2
3027514     44430     x^9 + 1, x0 = 3
 552764     43801     x^10 + 1, x0 = 2
 568909     43823     x^10 + 1, x0 = 3
8623590     44741     x^11 + 1, x0 = 2
8463129     44743     x^11 + 1, x0 = 3
 400465     43396     x^12 + 1, x0 = 2
 401493     43316     x^12 + 1, x0 = 3
8497977     44733     x^13 + 1, x0 = 2
8047224     44761     x^13 + 1, x0 = 3
 588730     43910     x^14 + 1, x0 = 2
 634799     43911     x^14 + 1, x0 = 3
1686343     44145     x^15 + 1, x0 = 2
2091292     44238     x^15 + 1, x0 = 3
 479840     43619     x^16 + 1, x0 = 2
 506561     43579     x^16 + 1, x0 = 3
8919461     44766     x^17 + 1, x0 = 2
8673652     44747     x^17 + 1, x0 = 3
 448822     43469     x^18 + 1, x0 = 2
 461822     43562     x^18 + 1, x0 = 3
8782917     44766     x^19 + 1, x0 = 2
8466664     44768     x^19 + 1, x0 = 3
```

Comment: Interesting observation, mostly degree $2$ is used, but it seems that other even degrees also have good performences.(+1)

Comment: [Scott Fluhrer's post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.crypt/yMVIKpYk5_Q) makes the claim that Polland rho will be very slow if the polynomial you are using is a permutation polynomial modulo one of $p$ and $q$. But this can easily happen if the polynomial is $x^k + 1$ for an odd $k$ (indeed, it happens whenever $k$ is coprime to $p-1$), whereas it will never happen if it is $x^k + 1$ for an even $k$ (unless $p=2$). This should explain part of your discrepancy. (That said, Scott Fluhrer's post is not a rigorous proof of anything.)

Comment: Scott Fluhrer's posts (until June 2010) state that if $a$ is coprime with $m$ then $ax + c$ is a permutation, where $m$ is the modulus.  This is necessary, but not sufficient for us to get a maximum period, hence a permutation.  See Theorem A, section 3.2.1.2, The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2, .Donald Knuth, 3rd edition, 1997.  Also, Fluhrer is talking about a linear function $ax + c$, not a degree-$k$ polynomial $x^k + 1 \pmod{m}$ like you. 
 Can you cite a reference for $x^k + 1 \pmod{m}$ for odd $k$ yielding a permutation?  I don't think Knuth addresses that and that'd answer it.

Comment: If $k$ is coprime to $p-1$, then the map $x \mapsto x^k$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a permutation (this follows from elementary group theory, since the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$), and therefore the map $x \mapsto x^k+1$ is a permutation as well. I am not saying that this guarantees large periods -- maybe the permutations have small order or consist of small cycles --; but it makes it plausible to me. And it is a behavior not encountered for even $k$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Can you explain what do you call a permutation here?  Are you saying that taking the set of elements of cyclic group G and applying a map $g \to g^k$ for all $g \in G$ yields the same set, just a little scrambled?

Comment: If the cyclic group has order coprime to $k$, then yes.